# probability winning game with changing winning conditions

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have the following problem:
Suppose I have a 10 level game. You start at level 0, your direction is upwards (this will be of importance later). At each timestep you can ascend or descend a Level. The probability of you going into the direction you are currently heading is T. The probability of you going into the opposite direction you are heading is (1-T), in this case you swap directions.
You win if you reach level 10, game over when you "reach level -1".

I am now interested in distribution of the players winning the game by timx x:
How many of k players do win the game in 10 steps of time, how many in 11, in 42, ...

I thank everyone of you tries to help me!
Cheers Rucki

[image: visualization]

Comment: Where did you get this problem? Is it supposed to have some sort of formula for an answer?

Comment: Me and my team are doing an Engineering project (shock absorbing stiff dampener through multilayering materials). We are observing practial proof of concept, but wed really like some sort of math formula to compare our meassures with a theoretical prediction.

All we have atm is a Matlab simulation which gives us an empirical distribution, but a formula would be nicer